# Google BigQuery data consistency model

Tags: google-bigquery, eventual-consistency

Short version: Is BQ strongly consistent?

Longer version: Suppose data is inserted in parallel into BQ table. One of the fields is set to `NOW()`. Can it be assumed that this field will only monotonously increase?

The use case is the following: read a bunch of records from BQ table then continue from last read TS. The tricky part – if for some reason a record appears later but with lower TS, then this record will be lost.

Is BQ is at all suitable for the above use-case?

Comment: If insertions are in parallel, then what does it mean for `NOW()` to be monotonically increasing?

Comment: It means for some other periodic read query this field is always increasing. So, it is safe to take max TS from previous query and make next with `>= TS`. If the value is not monotonously increasing, then we risk to miss some records.

Comment: That should be safe to assume. Really it's a question of how much clock skew there can theoretically be between data centers, e.g. if two jobs were scheduled in different cells. While BigQuery itself doesn't manage clock synchronization in data centers, projects such as [Spanner](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.wired.com/2012/11/google-spanner-time/amp/) rely on consistency.

Comment: Thanks @ElliottBrossard. Just to confirm (apart from possible clock skew) a record becomes visible as soon as its `NOW()` value is calculated? I can easily imagine a case where `NOW()` is calculated at T1, then a record gets delayed somewhere in the pipeline, and becomes visible only at T2. Not saying this is what actually happens at BQ, but you get the point.

Comment: We calculate `NOW()` (or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`/`CURRENT_TIME()`/etc. in standard SQL) based on the time that the query started, so if queries Q1 and Q2 both start at time T but take different times to complete, the value of `NOW()` will still reflect T.

Comment: Thanks! This is almost exactly what I was looking for in this answer. The use-case I presented in the question will not work, unless sequential read queries are started with `>= last TS - max(query time)`. The latter part is rather obscure, though. Any suggestions what could be max insert query time? Seconds? Minutes?

Comment: A second or more should be safe, since clock skew will be at most on the order of milliseconds.